# Retrieve all data for specific coin pair (Python-Binance API)

Tags: python, api, binance

I have a bit of code that will download minute to minute data historically from binance, and combine it all into their own CSV. EG: `BCHUSDT-1m-data.csv`, `BTCUSDT-1m-data.csv`, etc for whatever pairs I want. However, I keep getting a
`requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError connectionreset error 10054 (closed by remote host)`.

Is there a better way to go about getting this information than using the `client.get_historical_klines(interval)` method? Ideally I would want even more granular data (30s, 15, or even 1s if at all possible historically). Thanks in advance!

Link to API: [Python-Binance API](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Take a look at their [websocket](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/websockets.html) page, it allows you to stream data and get updates every second however I believe [Binance API](https://github.com/binance-us/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md#klinecandlestick-streams) is limited to 1m granularity

Answer (score 0):

For less than 1m trades you need to use

```
trades = client.get_historical_trades(symbol='BNBBTC')
```

or

```
trades = client.get_aggregate_trades(symbol='BNBBTC')
```

The last one is better it cost less weight and contains more information
Then if you want to combine it to candles/klines you can use pandas resample or ohlc function.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a go and if all goes well I'll mark as the answer!

Comment: Did this work for you? It seems like most of the 10054 posts i've seen have been using time's sleep function, are you using that anywhere?